# Using ng-repeat with ng-model modifies wrong object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

TLDR: Here's a plnkr of the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/HfRoCgPfdoZNxmTtDLf7?p=preview

I have a form with checkboxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rental.car2go.airport.berlin"> Berlin
      </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rental.car2go.airport.hamburg"> Hamburg
      </label>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

that is modifying the rental object. This is how the controller looks like:

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp', []).controller('c2gyoAppController', [
'$scope',
'state',
function($scope, state) {
  $scope.airports = [{
    "name": "Berlin",
    "model": "rental.car2go.airport.berlin"
  }, {
    "name": "Hamburg",
    "model": "rental.car2go.airport.hamburg"
  }, ];

  $scope.rental = state.rental;

}]).factory('state', function() {

var rental = {
  car2go: {
    airport: {
      berlin: false,
      hamburg: false
    }
  }
};

return {
  rental: rental
};
});
```

Now I want to use ng-repeat:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <span ng-repeat="airport in airports">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
             ng-model="airport.model">
                {{airport.name}}
      </label>
      <br>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With ng-repeat the form is modifying the airports object (`airports[1].model=true/false` and `airports[2].model=true/false`).

It should only use the string of that airport object(`rental.car2go.airport.berlin` and `rental.car2go.airport.hamburg` ) and modify the rental object. I'm looking for a way to pass the string to ng-model, not the airports object. How can I do this?

*Edit: removed the directive, new plnkr*

Comment: It is not clear why you claim that it is not working correctly. The **value** of a checkbox is either `true` or `false` and hence the replacement is as you observe (in both examples).

Comment: It probably is working correctly, but not how I want it ;) Check the plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/HfRoCgPfdoZNxmTtDLf7?p=preview) I want to modify a different object(rental.car2go.airport.xxx) than the one that gets passed to ng-repeat (airports).

Comment: angular doesn't support this way of binding `ng-model`.  I experimented a bit with a few options like using the `ng-modelOptions` getter/setter, but couldn't find an option that worked.  you will probably have to do something like bind the checkbox to a property on `airport`, and then copy the value to the `rental` array in an `ng-click` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as @Claies suggested I had to copy the value to the rental array. I used a `ng-change` function for that. New ng-repeat:

```
<span ng-repeat="airport in airports">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-model="airport.model"
           ng-change="changeAirport(airport)">
    {{airport.name}}
  </label>
  <br>
</span>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.changeAirport = function(airport) {
  var airportName = $filter('lowercase')(airport.name);
  state.rental.car2go.airport[airportName] = airport.model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are changing is:

```
$scope.airports = [{
    "airport": "Berlin",
    "model": "rental.car2go.airport.berlin"
  }, {
    "airport": "Hamburg",
    "model": "rental.car2go.airport.hamburg"
  }, ];
```

where `airports[0].model="rental.car2go.airport.berlin", meaning the string **rental.car2go.airport.berlin**. This string is replaced with TRUE or FALSE. I guess that you were expecting **rental.car2go.airport.berlin** to be interpreted as a structure, right? Well, it is not a structure but just a string.

Comment: Yeah I was expecting that. So how would the solution look like that the object `rental.car2go.airport.berlin` is modified?

Comment: You have to properly structure your JSON such that each element is in fact an object, like "`airport`" and "`model`" are.

Comment: `$scope.rental` and `$scope.airports` have to remain different objects

Comment: You can add hierarchy of object under rental. I suggest you review some docs about JSON and, if my answer was of any help, up-vote it.